# Почему при деполое динамический сайт ведет себя как статический?

Tags: развертывание, fastapi

При развертывании динамического сайта, он ведет себя как статический - запускается только index.html. При POST-запросе сервер не отвечает и я теперь не знаю как посмотреть что не в порядке.
Сам сайт можно посмотреть [здесь](https://mindeliveryprice.ru/), код от него [тут](https://github.com/bimka/min_price).

Как я понимаю мне нужен сервер - его роль выполняет uvicorn, он должен запускаться через main.py:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run('main:app', port=80, host='31.31.198.22')
```

но как я понимаю, main.py вообще не запускается, хотя на локальной машине при разработке все было хорошо.

Как нормально запустить динамический сайт?

PS: хостинг от reg.ru

Comment: Нужно смотреть что у вас за хостинг, и как там настраивается запуск вебсервера.

Comment: Вот, теперь гуглите как на reg.ru развернуть сайт на Django или Flask, потом в инструкции меняете gunicorn на uvicorn